# Design for a Java Banking program

Tags: java, finance

**UPDATE**: Added concise problem summary and sample output log.

I tried coding a sample Java program to solve a problem statement:

- [Java Banking Demo Problem statement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9cFP8YSr1FmSlJOanp2MFVKZkk/view?usp=sharing)
- [Complete code for Java Banking Demo](https://github.com/eanurag/BankingDemo)

**Concise Problem summary:**

> Design and Implement an Engine that processes the SMS messages which
>   are sent from a users device (mobile). The messages will come to
>   engine as plain text data.
>
> The message contains instructions to
>
> 1. Process a banking transaction
> 2. Modify a users proﬁle
>
> Based on messages mentioned above, the messages can be of two types:
>
> 1. Transaction request that makes changes to the account
> 2. Request to modify user proﬁle
>
> The operation corresponding to each type of message can have a pre and
>   post step and the actual operation step.
>
> Important
>
> 1. Assume each user has a ﬁxed. pre-deﬁned and unique
>
> Mobile Number Authentication PIN Transaction PIN Email Id
>
> Populate this information in an in memory data structure / file system
>   which can be used for authentication. Authentication of PIN will
>   involve just validating the mobiie number against PIN numbers and
>   making sure they are same as expected values.

**Sample output log**

```
Enter the no of records:
1
Enter the record no:1
anurag|anurag@gmail.com|8105720566|7|2708|2708
Record written to the transaction file: anurag|anurag@gmail.com|8105720566|7|2708|2708
Enter the no of transactions:
1
Enter the transaction no:1
mo|7|7|200|2708|2708|anurag@eanurag.com
User found in the transaction file: anurag|anurag@gmail.com|8105720566|7|2708|2708
8105720566:PIN authenticated
User found in the transaction file: anurag|anurag@gmail.com|8105720566|7|2708|2708
Record written to the transaction file: anurag|anurag@eanurag.com|8105720566|7|2708|2708
8105720566:Update completed for mo|7|7|200|2708|2708|anurag@eanurag.com
```

**`User`:**

```
package com.banking.businessobject;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Objects;

public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private BigInteger mobileNumber;
    private Account account;

    public User(String userName, String email, BigInteger mobileNumber,
            Account account) {
        this.userName = userName.toLowerCase();
        this.email = email.toLowerCase();
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.account = account;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email.toLowerCase();
    }

    public BigInteger getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(BigInteger mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return userName + "|" + email + "|" + mobileNumber + "|" + account;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        User user = (User) obj;
        return (this.userName.equals(user.getUserName())
                && this.email.equals(user.getEmail())
                && this.mobileNumber.intValue() == user.getMobileNumber()
                        .intValue() && this.account.equals(user.getAccount()));

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Objects.hash(this.userName, this.email, this.mobileNumber,
                this.account);
    }
}
```

**`Account`:**

```
package com.banking.businessobject;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Account {
    private Integer accountNumber;
    private Integer authPin;
    private Integer transactionPin;

    public Account(Integer accountNumber, Integer authPin,
            Integer transactionPin) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.authPin = authPin;
        this.transactionPin = transactionPin;
    }

    public Integer getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(Integer accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public Integer getAuthPin() {
        return authPin;
    }

    public void setAuthPin(Integer authPin) {
        this.authPin = authPin;
    }

    public Integer getTransactionPin() {
        return transactionPin;
    }

    public void setTransactionPin(Integer transactionPin) {
        this.transactionPin = transactionPin;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return accountNumber + "|" + authPin + "|" + transactionPin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Account account = (Account) obj;
        return (this.accountNumber.intValue() == account.getAccountNumber()
                .intValue()
                && this.authPin.intValue() == account.getAuthPin().intValue() && this.transactionPin
                    .intValue() == account.getTransactionPin().intValue());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Objects.hash(this.accountNumber, this.authPin,
                this.transactionPin);
    }
}
```

**`Transaction`:**

```
package com.banking.businessobject;

public class Transaction {
    // format of transaction message will be as below
    // tx|101|102|20000|pass11|pass22|anurag@eanurag.com
    // mo| | | |pass11|pass22|newemail@gmail.com
    private String transactionType;
    private Integer fromAccountNumber;
    private Integer toAccountNumber;
    private Integer transactionAmount;
    private Integer authPin;
    private Integer transactionPin;
    private String email;

    public Transaction(String[] messageArray) {
        this.transactionType = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
        this.fromAccountNumber = Integer.valueOf(messageArray[1]);
        this.toAccountNumber = Integer.valueOf(messageArray[2]);
        this.transactionAmount = Integer.valueOf(messageArray[3]);
        this.authPin = Integer.valueOf(messageArray[4]);
        this.transactionPin = Integer.valueOf(messageArray[5]);
        this.email = messageArray[6].toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType.toLowerCase();
    }

    public Integer getFromAccountNumber() {
        return fromAccountNumber;
    }

    public void setFromAccountNumber(Integer fromAccountNumber) {
        this.fromAccountNumber = fromAccountNumber;
    }

    public Integer getToAccountNumber() {
        return toAccountNumber;
    }

    public void setToAccountNumber(Integer toAccountNumber) {
        this.toAccountNumber = toAccountNumber;
    }

    public Integer getTransactionAmount() {
        return transactionAmount;
    }

    public void setTransactionAmount(Integer transactionAmount) {
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    }

    public Integer getAuthPin() {
        return authPin;
    }

    public void setAuthPin(Integer authPin) {
        this.authPin = authPin;
    }

    public Integer getTransactionPin() {
        return transactionPin;
    }

    public void setTransactionPin(Integer transactionPin) {
        this.transactionPin = transactionPin;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email.toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return transactionType + "|" + fromAccountNumber + "|" + toAccountNumber + "|" + transactionAmount + "|"
                + authPin + "|" + transactionPin + "|" + email;
    }
}
```

Implementation/helper classes for `FileIO`, `Sms` mocking and `Transaction` (I have also extracted each of these into an interface):

**`FileIO`:**

```
package com.banking.implementation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import com.banking.businessobject.Account;
import com.banking.businessobject.User;
import com.banking.interfaces.IFileIO;

public class FileIO implements IFileIO {
    // Test path for Windows machine
//  private final static String TRANSACTION_FILE = "c:\\bank_transaction.txt";

    // Test path for MacBook
     private final static String TRANSACTION_FILE =
     "/Users/anurag/bank_transaction.txt";


    @Override
    public boolean intitalizeTransactionFile() {
        // Initialize the file
        try {
            File file = new File(TRANSACTION_FILE);

            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("Transaction File created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Transaction File already exists");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // check if this actually returns false
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public User readTransactionFile(User user) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String currentLine = "";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(TRANSACTION_FILE));
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentLine.contains(user.getEmail().toLowerCase())) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] objectValue = currentLine.trim().split("\\|");
        Account account = new Account(Integer.valueOf(objectValue[3]),
                Integer.valueOf(objectValue[4]),
                Integer.valueOf(objectValue[5]));
        User newUser = new User(objectValue[0], objectValue[1], new BigInteger(
                objectValue[2]), account);
        System.out.println("User found in the transaction file: "
                + newUser.toString());
        return newUser;

        // to add exception code here if the record is not found
    }


    @Override
    public boolean writeTransactionFile(User user) {
        // **important**
        // Eclipse needs to be *Run as Admin* to have the write access to write
        // to the file
        // Problem with Windows 7+ as of now. Still need to check on Mac.

        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        String currentLine = "";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(TRANSACTION_FILE));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(TRANSACTION_FILE + ".tmp",
                    true));

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentLine.contains(user.getMobileNumber().toString()
                        .toLowerCase())) {
                    continue;
                }
                bw.write(currentLine);
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.write(user.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // check if flush is important
            bw.flush();
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File oldFile = new File(TRANSACTION_FILE);
        File newFile = new File(TRANSACTION_FILE + ".tmp");
        if (oldFile.delete()) {
            newFile.renameTo(oldFile);
        }

        // again check for error handling here
        System.out.println("Record written to the transaction file: "
                + user.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

**`Sms`:**

```
package com.banking.implementation;

import com.banking.businessobject.Transaction;
import com.banking.businessobject.User;
import com.banking.interfaces.ISmsGateway;
import com.banking.interfaces.ITransaction;

public class SmsGatewayImpl implements ISmsGateway {

    private String authPinNotification = "";
    private String transPinNotification = "";
    private String transactionNotification = "";
    private String profileUpdateNotification = "";

    public String getAuthPinNotification() {
        return authPinNotification;
    }

    public String getTransPinNotification() {
        return transPinNotification;
    }

    public String getTransactionNotification() {
        return transactionNotification;
    }

    public String getProfileUpdateNotification() {
        return profileUpdateNotification;
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveNextMessage(String message, User user) {
        // format of transaction message will be as below
        // tx|101|102|20000|pass11|pass22|anurag@eanurag.com
        // mo| | | |pass11|pass22|newemail@gmail.com
        String[] messageArray = message.trim().split("\\|");
        Transaction trnObj = new Transaction(messageArray);
        ITransaction trnImpl = new TransactionImpl();

        boolean authenticated = trnImpl.accountAuthentication(user, trnObj);

        switch (trnObj.getTransactionType().toLowerCase()) {
        case "tx":
            authPinNotification = notifyPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);
            if (!authPinNotification.isEmpty() && authPinNotification != null) {
                System.out.println(authPinNotification);
            }
            if (trnObj.getTransactionAmount() > 1000) {
                transPinNotification = notifyTransPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);

                if (!transPinNotification.isEmpty() && transPinNotification != null) {
                    System.out.println(transPinNotification);
                }
            }
            transactionNotification = notifyTransactionResult(user, trnObj, authenticated);
            if (!transactionNotification.isEmpty() && transactionNotification != null) {
                System.out.println(transactionNotification);
            }
            break;

        case "mo":
            authPinNotification = notifyPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);
            if (!authPinNotification.isEmpty() && authPinNotification != null) {
                System.out.println(authPinNotification);
            }

            trnImpl.profileUpdate(user, trnObj);

            profileUpdateNotification = notifyProfileUpdateResult(user, trnObj, authenticated);

            if (!profileUpdateNotification.isEmpty() && profileUpdateNotification != null) {
                System.out.println(profileUpdateNotification);
            }
            break;

        default:
            // add error handling code here
            System.out.println("Incorrect Transaction Query format");
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String notifyPinAuthenticationResult(User user, boolean authentication) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        if (authentication) {
            string.append(user.getMobileNumber().toString());
            string.append(":PIN authenticated");
            return string.toString();
        }
        string.append("Error:");
        string.append(user.getMobileNumber());
        string.append(":PIN authentication failed");
        return string.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String notifyTransPinAuthenticationResult(User user, boolean authentication) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        if (authentication) {
            string.append(user.getMobileNumber().toString());
            string.append(":TPIN authenticated");
            return string.toString();
        }
        string.append("Error:");
        string.append(user.getMobileNumber());
        string.append(":TPIN authentication failed");
        return string.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String notifyTransactionResult(User user, Transaction trnObj, boolean transaction) {
        if (transaction) {
            return (user.getMobileNumber() + ":Txn completed for " + trnObj.toString());
        }
        return ("Error:" + user.getMobileNumber() + ":Txn failed for " + trnObj.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String notifyProfileUpdateResult(User user, Transaction trnObj, boolean authenticated) {
        if (authenticated) {
            return (user.getMobileNumber() + ":Update completed for " + trnObj.toString());
        }
        return ("Error:" + user.getMobileNumber() + ":Update failed for " + trnObj.toString());
    }

}
```

**`Transaction`:**

```
package com.banking.implementation;

import com.banking.businessobject.Transaction;
import com.banking.businessobject.User;
import com.banking.interfaces.IFileIO;
import com.banking.interfaces.ITransaction;

public class TransactionImpl implements ITransaction {
    @Override
    public boolean accountAuthentication(User user, Transaction trnObj) {
        boolean authentication = false;
        IFileIO fi = new FileIO();
        User userRecord = fi.readTransactionFile(user);
        if (userRecord.getMobileNumber().intValue() == user.getMobileNumber()
                .intValue()
                && userRecord.getAccount().getAuthPin().intValue() == user
                        .getAccount().getAuthPin().intValue()) {
            if (trnObj.getTransactionType().toLowerCase().equals("tx")
                    && trnObj.getTransactionAmount().intValue() > 1000) {
                if (userRecord.getAccount().getTransactionPin().intValue() != user
                        .getAccount().getTransactionPin().intValue()) {
                    return authentication;
                }
            }

            authentication = true;
        }
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean profileUpdate(User user, Transaction trnObj) {

        IFileIO fi = new FileIO();

        User userRecord = fi.readTransactionFile(user);
        userRecord.setEmail(trnObj.getEmail());

        return fi.writeTransactionFile(userRecord);
    }
}
```

I have also created unit tests for the helper classes, which I think is not important to attach here.

I am just looking for honest feedback on the design, coding, or anything else on the code.

Comment: Could you include a small summary of the problem statement? We do not like relying much on external links

Comment: @Caridorc Thanks for pointing out! Added summary of the problem statement and sample output too.

Comment: Thanks for caring about improving the quality of your post, I hope we had more users like you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TransactionImpl#accountAuthentication

I'll start with `accountAuthentication` method from TransactionImpl:

```
@Override
public boolean accountAuthentication(User user, Transaction trnObj) {
    boolean authentication = false;
    IFileIO fi = new FileIO();
    User userRecord = fi.readTransactionFile(user);
    if (userRecord.getMobileNumber().intValue() == user.getMobileNumber()
            .intValue()
            && userRecord.getAccount().getAuthPin().intValue() == user
            .getAccount().getAuthPin().intValue()) {
        if (trnObj.getTransactionType().toLowerCase().equals("tx")
                && trnObj.getTransactionAmount().intValue() > 1000) {
            if (userRecord.getAccount().getTransactionPin().intValue() != user
                    .getAccount().getTransactionPin().intValue()) {
                return authentication;
            }
        }

        authentication = true;
    }
    return authentication;
}
```

You can extract the big if in a separate method:

```
@Override
public boolean accountAuthentication(User user, Transaction trnObj) {
    boolean authentication = false;
    IFileIO fi = new FileIO();
    User userRecord = fi.readTransactionFile(user);
    if (isBadAuthentication(user, trnObj, userRecord)) {
        return authentication;
    }
    authentication = true;

    return authentication;
}
```

Then we can get rid of `authentication` temp variable:

```
public boolean accountAuthentication2(User user, Transaction trnObj) {
    IFileIO fi = new FileIO();
    User userRecord = fi.readTransactionFile(user);
    return verifyAuthentication(user, trnObj, userRecord);
}
```

Now for the `verifyAuthentication` method, I extracted each condition in a separate method 
and inverted the negative conditions. If we need to check for a negative, we can use `!`.

```
private boolean verifyAuthentication(User user, Transaction trnObj, User userRecord) {
    return verifyMobilePhone(user, userRecord) &&
           verifyAuthPin(user, userRecord) &&
           !isTxTransaction(trnObj) &&
           !hasBigAmount(trnObj) &&
           verifyTransactionPin(user, userRecord);
}

private boolean verifyTransactionPin(User user, User userRecord) {
    return userRecord.getAccount().getTransactionPin().intValue() ==
           user.getAccount().getTransactionPin().intValue();
 }

private boolean hasBigAmount(Transaction trnObj) {
    return trnObj.getTransactionAmount().intValue() > 1000;
}

private boolean isTxTransaction(Transaction trnObj) {
    return trnObj.getTransactionType().toLowerCase().equals("tx");
}

private boolean verifyAuthPin(User user, User userRecord) {
    return userRecord.getAccount().getAuthPin().intValue() ==
           user.getAccount().getAuthPin().intValue();
}

private boolean verifyMobilePhone(User user, User userRecord) {
    return userRecord.getMobileNumber().intValue() ==
           user.getMobileNumber().intValue();
}
```

We have many small methods now, but we can easily move them to their related class. 
For example, we move `isTxTransaction` and `hasBigAmount` right in the `Transaction` class:

**Transaction.java** :

```
public boolean isTx() {
    return getTransactionType().toLowerCase().equals("tx");
}

public boolean hasBigAmount() {
    return getTransactionAmount().intValue() > 1000;
}
```

**TransactionImpl.java** :

```
private boolean verifyAuthentication(User user, Transaction trnObj, User userRecord) {
    return verifyMobilePhone(user, userRecord) &&
           verifyAuthPin(user, userRecord) &&
           !trnObj.isTx() &&
           !trnObj.hasBigAmount() &&
           verifyTransactionPin(user, userRecord);
}
```

Integers are automatically unboxed, there is no need to call `intValue` in `hasBigAmount`:

```
public boolean hasBigAmount() {
    return getTransactionAmount() > 1000;
}
```

## SmsGatewayImpl#receiveNextMessage

`receiveNextMessage` has this big switch:

```
switch (trnObj.getTransactionType().toLowerCase()) {
    case "tx":
        authPinNotification = notifyPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);
        if (!authPinNotification.isEmpty() && authPinNotification != null) {
            System.out.println(authPinNotification);
        }
        if (trnObj.getTransactionAmount() > 1000) {
            transPinNotification = notifyTransPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);

            if (!transPinNotification.isEmpty() && transPinNotification != null) {
                System.out.println(transPinNotification);
            }
        }
        transactionNotification = notifyTransactionResult(user, trnObj, authenticated);
        if (!transactionNotification.isEmpty() && transactionNotification != null) {
            System.out.println(transactionNotification);
        }
        break;

    case "mo":
        authPinNotification = notifyPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);
        if (!authPinNotification.isEmpty() && authPinNotification != null) {
            System.out.println(authPinNotification);
        }

        trnImpl.profileUpdate(user, trnObj);

        profileUpdateNotification = notifyProfileUpdateResult(user, trnObj, authenticated);

        if (!profileUpdateNotification.isEmpty() && profileUpdateNotification != null) {
            System.out.println(profileUpdateNotification);
        }
        break;

    default:
        // add error handling code here
        System.out.println("Incorrect Transaction Query format");
        break;
}
```

`authPinNotification` is printed in both cases, it can be extracted in a separate method.
You can also extract each case in a method. 
I also used the `hasBigAmount` method extracted earlier.

```
printAuthPinNotification(user, authenticated);
switch (trnObj.getTransactionType().toLowerCase()) {
    case "tx":
        processTxTransaction(user, trnObj, authenticated);
        break;

    case "mo":
        processMoTransaction(user, trnObj, trnImpl, authenticated);
        break;

    default:
        // add error handling code here
        System.out.println("Incorrect Transaction Query format");
        break;
    }
}

private void printAuthPinNotification(User user, boolean authenticated) {
    authPinNotification = notifyPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);
    if (authPinNotification != null && !authPinNotification.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(authPinNotification);
    }
}

private void processMoTransaction(User user, Transaction trnObj, ITransaction trnImpl, boolean authenticated) {
    trnImpl.profileUpdate(user, trnObj);

    profileUpdateNotification = notifyProfileUpdateResult(user, trnObj, authenticated);

    if (profileUpdateNotification != null && !profileUpdateNotification.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(profileUpdateNotification);
    }
}


private void processTxTransaction(User user, Transaction trnObj, boolean authenticated) {
    if (trnObj.hasBigAmount()) {
        transPinNotification = notifyTransPinAuthenticationResult(user, authenticated);

        if (transPinNotification != null && !transPinNotification.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(transPinNotification);
        }
    }
    transactionNotification = notifyTransactionResult(user, trnObj, authenticated);
    if (transactionNotification != null && !transactionNotification.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(transactionNotification);
    }
}
```

## Transaction type

Consider having an enum for transaction type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Subtle changes but makes a lot of sense in design.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub <- this line here
    return Objects.hash(this.userName, this.email, this.mobileNumber,
            this.account);
}
```

Umm... I think your `hashCode()` method is done...

This:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String currentLine = "";

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(TRANSACTION_FILE));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(TRANSACTION_FILE + ".tmp",
                true));

        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (currentLine.contains(user.getMobileNumber().toString()
                    .toLowerCase())) {
                continue;
            }
            bw.write(currentLine);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.write(user.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // check if flush is important
        bw.flush();
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

First thing's first. *Never* catch `Exception`. *Always* catch the specific exception that might be thrown. In this case, `IOException` (I believe).

Next, it can be improved by using Java 7's try-with-resources:

```
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(TRANSACTION_FILE),
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(TRANSACTION_FILE + ".tmp", true))) {
        String currentLine = "";
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (currentLine.contains(user.getMobileNumber().toString()
                    .toLowerCase())) {
                continue;
            }
            bw.write(currentLine);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.write(user.toString());
        bw.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Disclaimer: not tested.